# unfold function in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, functools

I have started practicing functional programming in python recently.

Lets say I define a function that gets an array of digits and concatenates it:

```
In [1]: def fromDigits(digits):
   ...:     return reduce(lambda x,y: 10*x+y,digits,0)
   ...:

In [2]: fromDigits([1,2,3,4,5])
Out[2]: 12345
```

Now I want to implement the reverse function:

```
def toDigits(num):
   return unfold(lambda m,digits: (m/10,digits+[m % 10]) if m>0 else None,  num,  [])
```

But I couldn't find a definition of `unfold` in the `python` functools or anywhere in the standard library.

Comment: Write it, then. Python doesn't have that built-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfold is not a python function ... here is a recursive solution ...

```
def to_digits(x):
    if not x: return []
    return to_digits(x//10) + [x%10]

to_digits(12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of functional programming, you can use `map` in python.
One example is:
`map(lambda a, b: a+b, [1,2,3], [2,3,4])`
which will return `[3, 5, 7]`.

In your case, you can do:

```
def toDigits(num):
    return map(int, str(num))
```

Comment: Sure, they could use a for loop too, but the question is about unfold

Answer (score 0):

There is no `unfold` implementation in the standard library. However, there is a similar function in the `more_itertools` module. You can use [more_itertools.iterate](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.iterate) to generate the array. `more_itertools.iterate` can be considered as a nonterminating version of `unfold`, so you need `itertools.takewhile` to terminate the iterator.

```py
from more_itertools import iterate, always_reversible
from itertools import takewhile

def to_digits(num):
  return always_reversible(
    map(
      lambda x: x % 10,
      takewhile(
        lambda x: x > 0,
        iterate(lambda x: x // 10, num)
      )
    )
  )

print(*to_digits(12345))
```

If you prefer functions from the standard library, you might want to use [itertools.accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), which can be considered as a more powerful version of `more_itertools.iterate`, because `itertools.accumulate` takes an additional iterable parameter. Since you don't need the additional iterable for generating digits, just pass `repeat(None)` to fall back to the `more_itertools.iterate` behavior.

```py
from itertools import takewhile, accumulate, repeat

def to_digits(num):
  return reversed(
    tuple(
      map(
        lambda x: x % 10,
        takewhile(
          lambda x: x > 0,
          accumulate(repeat(None), lambda x, _: x // 10, initial=num)
        )
      )
    )
  )

print(*to_digits(12345))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution with `unfoldr`

```
# Python 3.8+

from collections import deque


def unfold(s, f):
    state, elements = s, deque()
    while (next_step := f(state)) is not None:
        state, element = next_step
        elements.appendleft(element)
    return list(elements)


def to_digits(num):
    return unfold(num, lambda n: (n // 10, n % 10) if n > 0 else None)


>>> to_digits(12345)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

### From the Question

The different parts of the logic proposed in the question are:

```
def toDigits(num):
   return unfold(lambda m,digits: (m/10,digits+[m % 10]) if m>0 else None,  num,  [])
#                                  +--+         +----+      +-+
# compute the next state  <--------+            |           |
#                                               |           |
# compute the element  <------------------------+           |
#                                                           |
# predicate to terminate `unfold`  <------------------------+
```

However I think these following parts should not belong to the function to pass but to the `unfold` logic itself:

```
def toDigits(num):
  return unfold(lambda m,digits: (m/10,digits+[m % 10]) if m^0 else None,  num,  [])
#                        +----+        +------+      ++                          ++
```

### A new Function

The function to pass to `unfold` could simply be:

```
lambda n: (n // 10, n % 10) if n > 0 else None
#+------+    ++
#       |     +---> floor division operator 
#       |
#       +---------> input   just the number
#                   output  the next state and the element "unfolded"
#                           (or None)
```

And the type signature would be:

```
S = TypeVar('S')  # state
A = TypeVar('A')  # element to unfold

f: Callable[[S], Optional[Tuple[S, A]]] = lambda n: (n // 10, n % 10) if n > 0 else None
#           +-+                 +--+
#           |                   |
#  input  <-+                   |
#                               |
#  output <---------------------+
```

### Unfold(r)

Looking at the logic proposed in the question, we could assume the `unfold` expected is actually the "right-hand flavor" `unfoldr`. A possible implementation (Python 3.8+) could be:

```
from collections import deque  # O(1) `appendleft`

def unfoldr(s, f):
    state, elements = s, deque()
    while (next_step := f(state)) is not None:
        state, element = next_step
        elements.appendleft(element)
    return list(elements)
```

Where the signature is:

```
def unfoldr(state: S, f: Callable[[S], Optional[Tuple[S, A]]]) -> List[A]:
```

BTW if you prefer creating stack frames with a recursive implementation:

```
def unfoldr(state, f):
    return [] if (next_step := f(state)) is None else unfoldr(next_step[0], f) + [next_step[1]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't use `lambda`, it uses list comprehension:

```
def to_digits(x):
    return [int(i) for i in str(x)]
```

`str(x)` is an iterable with the stringified version of `x`, and the list comprehension makes it into a list of integers (hence `int(i)`).

Comment: `iter(str(x))` is superfluous.

Comment: And while `list(str(x))` does indeed return an iterable, a list to be exact, just `str(x)` is already iterable.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga